# document.getElementFromPoint() for covered item

Tags: javascript, jquery

Doing some research, I've come across the `document.getElementFromPoint(x,y)` method, and it's almost exactly what I want, except I don't want the topmost element.

Pretend I have said markup:

```
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="bottom"></div>
```

with this CSS:

```
div { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
#top {
    z-index: 1;
}
#bottom {
    z-index: 0;
}
```

With that, performing `document.getElementFromPoint(0,0)` would return `<div id="top"></div>`.

What I'm wondering is if there is a moderately simple (no plugins please) way to target `#bottom` via a cursor point.

Comment: @DavidThomas I can do that, but I'm using #top for something else on a hover, so I don't want to disable it.

Comment: I deleted the comment, because I don't think it would work anyway.

Comment: @DavidThomas Actually it would, if I didn't need that other element for other stuff.

Comment: Set the style, run `elementFromPoint()`, reset the style.